# putting trend line, regression value, and kendall taus value in r

Tags: r, plot, regression

I have a year and annual temperature data. I ran kendall tau correlation between time and year, regression, and t-test in the data.

```
Now i want to plot the data (Time~Temperature). My data is as follows;
Year    Annual mean
1948    9.052924791
1949    9.728310502
1950    7.984018265
1951    7.99391172
1952    9.630388585
1953    10.35083714
1954    10.08980213
1955    9.812785388
1956    10.12480974
1957    9.187214612
1958    8.658295282
1959    9.857686454
1960    9.43989071
1961    9.221461187
1962    9.102739726
1963    8.627853881
1964    9.53476017
1965    9.050228311
1966    9.063926941
1967    8.942922374
1968    10.27018822
1969    9.780060883
1970    10.16590563
1971    10.75190259
1972    8.83955677
1973    10.92161339
1974    9.847031963
1975    10.67579909
1976    9.364754098
1977    10.42085236
1978    8.744292237
1979    9.121004566
1980    9.338660578
1981    9.512937595
1982    8.953576865
1983    9.645357686
1984    9.127959927
1985    8.525114155
1986    9.95585997
1987    11.23896499
1988    9.804327808
1989    9.136986301
1990    11.00989346
1991    10.78830891
1992    9.392835458
1993    9.322678843
1994    10.12633181
1995    10.08928571
1996    8.568609593
1997    9.242770167
1998    12.0456621
1999    10.78767123
2000    10.03035823
2001    10.51141553
2002    10.53805175
2003    9.496194825
2004    10.03483607
2005    10.74642857
2006    11.1509589
2007    10.79342466
2008    9.366256831
2009    9.372998478
2010    10.87214612
2011    10.44292237
2012    12.34390878
2013    9.564687976
2014    8.698158295
2015    10.14237443
2016    11.2704918
2017    11.42694064
2018    10.62660256
 My Codes so far;
    Install Necessary packages#
    install.packages("dplyr")
    library(dplyr)
    install.packages("tidyr")
    library(tidyr)
    install.packages("stringr")
    library(stringr)
    install.packages("Kendall")
    library(Kendall)
    dat1<-read.table("AnnualMean.csv", sep=",", header = T)
    x1<-dat1$Year
    y1<-dat1$Annual.mean
    Kendall(x1,y1)
    test<-t.test(y1)
    regress<-lm(x1~y1)
    plot( y1~x1 , type="b" , bty="l" , xlab="year" , ylab="Temp in Celcius")
    abline(regress, col="blue")
```

I want to put a trendline in my line graph, along with the tau value which is 0.20 that i calculated from Kendall tau, significant value from t.test, and rsquared value from regression in the legend of the graph. How do i proceed further?

Comment: Can it be done with `ggplot2`?

Comment: I would appreciete Pawel Chabros, if you could help with gplot. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `ggplot2` you can add yours statistics with `geom_label`:

```
x1 <- dat1$Year
y1 <- dat1$Annual_mean

kend_test <- Kendall(x1, y1)
t_test <- t.test(y1)
regr <- lm(x1~y1)

legend <- paste0(
    'tau: ', round(kend_test$tau, 2), '   ',
    'p-value: ', round(t_test$p.value, 2), '   ',
    'R^2: ', round(summary(regr)$r.squared, 2)
  )

dat1 %>%
  ggplot(aes(
    x = Year,
    y = Annual_mean
  )) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm', se = FALSE) +
  geom_label(aes(
      x = mean(x1),
      y = max(y1),
      label = legend
    ),
  )
```

Comment: No problem. I'm glad I could help :)

Comment: how do I put an equation like; y = 0.0198x + 9.1245 (y intercept) in the graph. thanks again

Comment: Sam as statistics, with `geom_label`. Values of the equation you can extract with `coefficients(regr)`. Than paste them with text. E.g. `paste0('y = ', round(coefficients(regr)[2], 4), 'x + ', round(coefficients(regr)[1]), 4)`

Comment: legend <- paste0(
  'tau: ', round(kend_test$tau, 2), '   ',
  'p-value: ', round(t_test$p.value, 2), '   ',
  'R^2: ', round(summary(regr)$r.squared, 2)
  'y = ', round(coefficients(regr)[2], 4), 'x + ', round(coefficients(regr)[1]), 4),
  )

dat1 %>%
  ggplot(aes(
    x = Year,
    y = Annual.Mean.Celcius
  )) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm', se = FALSE) +
  geom_label(aes(
    x = mean(x1),
    y = max(y1),
    label = legend
  ),
  ) I edited this but it wont paste the equation in the box

Comment: You had mistake in `paste0` function. Try this `legend <- paste0(
  'tau: ', round(kend_test$tau, 2), ' ',
  'p-value: ', round(t_test$p.value, 2), ' ',
  'R^2: ', round(summary(regr)$r.squared, 2), '\n',
  'y = ', round(coefficients(regr)[2], 4), 'x + ', round(coefficients(regr)[1], 4)
)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187726/discussion-between-lira-and-pawel-chabros).